# Using polychoric from psych to get correlation from ordinal and nominal variables

Tags: r, pca, psych

I'm trying to make a PCA for a dataset with ordinal and nominal variables (they are already converted to numeric), reading about the subject people [recommend](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5774/can-principal-component-analysis-be-applied-to-datasets-containing-a-mix-of-cont)  to use psych because pca use pearson correlation (the explanation and recommendation is a lot longer than just using polychoric but was one of the options), so I try to use polychoric and I get the error :

Warning in polychoric(studentest) :
The items do not have an equal number of response alternatives, global set to FALSE.
Warning in qnorm(cumsum(rsum)[-length(rsum)]) : NaNs produced
Error in if (any(lower > upper)) stop("lower>upper integration limits") :
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

I was looking for the reason of this error and I could find two answer, the error means that the variables have not the same range, because I'm using binomial and ordinal, and the second answer was that [someone](https://www.reddit.com/r/RStudio/comments/r54vk5/polychoric_function_psych_used_to_work_with_my/) could use the function to get the correlations but the package got an update, and  getting back to the prior version the code work again, so I wanted to know if polychoric is really  a good way to analyze  the binomial and ordinal together.

[This is the data set I was using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdKXe.png)

Comment: Hey there! Its helpful if you include your script to see what you've done so far to get to this point. It would also be helpful if you can create `dput` of that data you showed so nobody has to recreate it by scratch. Here is a link on how to do that:
https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error, and it seems that any version 2.0 or newer has this problem. You can overcome this by installing the last version prior to 2.0. Here is code to do this:

```
packageurl <- "https://cran.r- 
project.org/src/contrib/Archive/psych/psych_1.9.12.tar.gz"
install.packages(packageurl, repos=NULL, type="source")
```